# Based time travel , full color,historical, medical skill, romance and medic system

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga

A manga or manhua/manhwa about time travel, romance, ancient times, and a medical system. It's based on her wedding night where she meets her crippled husband( he cannot move his legs) on a wheelchair, whom later assassins try to kill her husband to prove if he can walk or not,then she has to complete the command and use the medical system to cure the injured people even the assassins.
It looks like ancient china.
Around the year 2017, 2018, 2019 is when i read it

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, I see you may have been struggling to formulate this question. I've done my level best to tidy that up, please [edit] if I've made a mistake with that. As always, please see our [help] and take the [tour]. Many thanks!

Comment: Is "Basex" supposed to be "Basic"? "Base X"? "Basex"?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Could this be *Gifted Toxic Princess* (AKA *Genius Poison Princess Consort Han Yun Xi*)?

> She is the most menial ugly daughter of a medical family, while he is
> the noblest prince in Kingdom Tianning. On their wedding day, when the
> bridal sedan chair reaches the Prince's mansion, the door is shut, she
> has no choice but to enter the mansion alone. Unexpectedly, the ugly
> girl is actually a gorgeous genius medic! Accidentally, she saves an
> assassin on her wedding night and promises him: Bro, hurry and leave,
> I won't get you exposed. However, the assassin says: it's our wedding
> night, where do you want me to go?

[image]